# How to recover when Jenkins jobs stop due to temporary loss of connectivity?

Tags: jenkins

I am working on a project with hundreds of Jenkins jobs, and some of them run automated tests for several hours (7, 8, even 10 hours). Unfortunately we've been experiencing network problems (WAN) and at least once a day we lose connectivity for several minutes. Then the jobs fail because the "Agent went offline":

`Agent went offline during the build ERROR: Connection was broken: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:73) Caused by: java.io.EOFException at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2332) at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2801) at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801) at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299) at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:48) at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34) at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:59)`

From my understanding, the Jenkins master uses the agent in each slave to request new jobs to run. In my project, once that is done all the tests are run locally and not remotely. Therefore, the slaves could (should?) continue to run the jobs in the background, and when the connectivity is restored to the master it can then catch up on the slave logs and status. I don't know the Jenkins architecture in depth, but this doesn't sound like an impossible task.

So this brings me to my questions: is it possible to do such recovery? Is it possible to keep the slave running isolated from the master for a while? I am sure other Jenkins users have had this problem before.